# JPA Query for "Set does NOT contain a certain item"

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql

Let's say we have a class `Person` which contains `Set<Book> books`.

To find all the persons *with* book "Effective Java", you could write:

```
select p from Person p left outer join fetch p.books as b where b.name='Effective Java'
```

Now, how can I turn this query on it's head, and find all the `Person` **without** this book?

```
select p from Person p "where p.books does not contain book b where b.name='Effective Java'"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take advantage of the `NOT EXISTS` keyword:

```
select p 
from Person p
where not exists (
   select b from p.books b where b.name = 'Effective Java'
)
```

Comment: Yeah, me too! Its much better to push this power back onto the database, instead of doing `persons.getBooks().stream.filter(....)` :) Much appreciated! Have a great weekend

Answer (score 0):

Or what about

```
 select p from Person p join p.books b where b.name <> 'Effective Java'
```